# Prevent access to files on linux file server

Tags: linux, security, file-server, privacy

I have a linux system running Debian Wheezy stable on it and am using it as a file repository (not a true file server because I am using BitTorrent sync to move files as I move around the world). Some family has expressed a desire to store data similarly but I would like to give them the space without me necessarily having direct access to their files.

I know there are some sites that if you store files on them they make it a point to let you know that they can't access it or they can't see it, etc. What mechanism are they using to achieve that level of privacy for their users? Are they able to still scan the directories for viruses or malware or by providing that kind of privacy, do they effectively make it where they cannot see the directory to scan? Or is it something else altogether (encryption, etc)?

My apologies if this is better asked somewhere else or if it has already been answered.

Thank you for your help!

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pretty much have to trust the administrators of a service with the data you upload to it.  Any assertion that a service provider cannot see data provided to it is dubious at best (speaking as a security professional).  Even if the provider restricts access or encrypts data, you still have to trust their access restrictions (and usually they will ultimately need access to the data somehow just to provide the service) and their encryption.  The only way to be reasonably certain is to encrypt the data yourself with your own encryption tools before uploading it.

Comment: Wholly agree with you that when they claim this it is dubious. I thought I would post it here to see if there was something I am missing. Thanks for the quick reply, Falcon.